# msvcr90.dll dependency cannot be located on windows 8.1

Tags: c++, visual-c++, dll, winsxs, msvcr90.dll

I am trying to build a VC++ (VS 2008) OCX (32 bit) project on a windows 8.1 64 bit machine.  The OCX is getting built OK, but not loading when trying to register using regsvr32.  Inspecting the binary using Dependency Walker shows MSVCR90.DLL as one of the missing dependencies.  However i can see that this dll is available in the respective folder under C:\windows\winSxs area.  Cant figure out why WinSxS is unable to locate the DLL.

The other dependencies that are reported as missing are

1. API-MS-WIN-CORE-KERNEL32-PRIVATE-L1-1-1.DLL
2. API-MS-WIN-CORE-PRIVATEPROFILE-L1-1-1.DLL
3. API-MS-WIN-SERVICE-PRIVATE-L1-1-1.DLL
4. API-MS-WIN-CORE-SHUTDOWN-L1-1-1.DLL
5. EXT-MS-WIN-NTUSER-UICONTEXT-EXT-L1-1-0.DLL
6. IESHIMS.DLL

Any idea what could be going wrong?

Thanks in advance..

Comment: Does this dll exist in `System32` / `SysWOW64` directories?

Answer (score 0):

Your installation of MS VS 2008 is incorrect. Reinstall it completely or move the dll to SysWOW64 directory.

Or you can install MS VC 2008 redist: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=29

Comment: I tried to reinstall teh VC2008 redist, but that didnt help.  Opened the OCX binary and checked the embedded manifest data.  It says

   <dependentAssembly>
      <assemblyIdentity type="win32" name="Microsoft.VC90.CRT" version="9.0.21022.8" processorArchitecture="x86" publicKeyToken="1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b"></assemblyIdentity>
    </dependentAssembly>
  </dependency>

And I do see a folder named x86_microsoft.vc90.crt_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.21022.8_none_bcb86ed6ac711f91 under WinSxS with msvcr90.dll and other two files inside.  

So not really sure why msvcr90.dll cannot be found by dependency walker